# How to find find element by a class and specific name attribute?

Tags: jquery

I have multiple elements, like

```
<a href="#" name="0" class="myClass">Link 0</a>
<a href="#" name="1" class="myClass">Link 1</a>
```

I need a jQuery selector to get them, like

```
var myElement = $(.myClass).attr("name"="0");
```

or so..

Is that possible?
Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Combine an [attribute selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) with the class selector:

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/37csrzb1/)

```
var $myElement = $('.myClass[name="0"]');
```

You were using the `.attr()` method which will either retrieve or set an element's attribute, not select an element with a given attribute.

---

If you want to replace the `0` value with a variable, you could use the following:

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/feodazpy/)

```
var number = 1,
    $myElement = $('.myClass[name="' + number + '"]');
```

Comment: Thank you! Just one more question: How do I replace the "0" with a variable?

Comment: @user980018 It would be `$('.myClass[name="' + number + '"]');` see the update.

Comment: Kinda obvious! :D Thanks! Really helped me!